# SQL- all rows which are present in all years

Tags: sql, select, relational-division

I have the following columns in my DB

```
Codes

year |  code   |
----------------
2009 | 10001   |
2009 | 10002   |
2009 | 10003   |

2010 | 10001   |
2010 | 10002   |
2010 | 10004   |

2011 | 10001   |
2011 | 10005   |
2011 | 10010   |
```

**How do I find all the codes which are preset in all years**. For example in the above I want only `10001` since its the only code which is present in all years. I've tried

```
SELECT code FROM Codes
GROUP BY code 
HAVING count(year) = 3
```

But this isn't very flexible since I may want to restrict this to a subset, for example, find all codes only in years 2010 and 2011.

Comment: Don't put "all [rows]" in front of a query spec. It's just confusing/misleading. It has nothing to do with queries involving "all" in the sense of division or "for all" queries. *Every* query spec means "all rows where...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT code 
FROM Codes
where year in (2010,2011,2012)
GROUP BY code 
HAVING count( distinct year ) = 3
```

Comment: `count(distinct year)` to be safe in case of duplicates.

Comment: @mikev3 . . . It is actually rude to change a question after it has been answered.  Your edit has invalidated this originally correct answer, and that can draw downvotes.  I would suggest that you remove the edit, accept this answer, and ask another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the comment.  It turns out that this does answer my original question anyways, and it was a misunderstanding on my part that lead me to edit, the changes have been reverted.