# Query to find a table with column names 'name1' and 'name2' etc all present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a query to find all table names with the table having all the columns in a list like ['name1','name2','name3','name4']

I have seen SQK queries where you can check for one column name, but I would like to do more, and **all** columns have to be there. I have come up with this, that is usable, I can check if all the names are in a table just looking at the rows, but this could improved I think. Maybe use exits?

```
FROM sys.columns col
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab
ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
WHERE col.name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4')
ORDER BY [Table Name], [Column Name] desc
```

(And after that checking if all the names are there manually)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701538/sql-all-rows-which-are-present-in-all-years) answer your question?

Comment: You mean: SELECT tab.name AS [Table Name]
FROM sys.columns col
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab
ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
WHERE col.name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4')
GROUP BY tab.name
Having count(distinct col.name) = 4

Comment: You should be grouping by object id not name and don't need distinct. `SELECT tab.name AS [Table Name] FROM sys.tables tab WHERE tab.object_id IN (SELECT col.object_id FROM sys.columns col WHERE col.name in ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4') GROUP BY col.object_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 4)`

Comment: Just tested it, it seems to be working. Thanks the both of you!

Comment: I know using 'having' here is a possibility but the other answer did not have any link to the problem I was having. Which was about table names and column names. So I would still think it is useful not to delete this question, because the answer would be hard to search for. Basically an answer is also 'you should use sql'. But I know moderators on stackoverflow by now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "other answer" but the linked duplicate does what you need. The fact that you are using the meta-data table to find "columns" in "tables" is not relevant. The same technique applies to finding "codes" in "years" or any similar <find all of these in those> situation. To really understand the third comment, create a table with the same name in different schemas and compare the results of your first query with that from Martin. There's a lot to learn here.

Comment: Yeah sure, no problem really, have a nice day.

Comment: I mean that in my view a little redundancy could even be good, trying to find an answer to questions. But I surely know that you do not agree with me about this. I have had these discussions before. So I won't redo them. Anyways, the answer is working, and I am studying the general concept of it, and I have written it down for myself. So, okay, just forget it. It is not that important. And I am very happy that you pointed me in the right direction.